# Where does this value in Firebase realtime db rules refer to?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

The rules for my firebase realtime db contain the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "projects":{
      ".indexOn": "parent_project_uuid",
      ".read":  true,
      "$UUID" : {
        "people" : {
          ".read" : "auth.uid === 'AIzaxxx'",
          ".write" : "auth.uid === 'AIzaxxx'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea where I can find the `AIzaxxx` value? I need that for the rules of another database but can't find where this value originates from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a hard-coded UID of a specific user, which means that specific user can read and write the entire `people` node of any specific user on a project.

I regularly do this myself when I'm just getting started on a project, I create a single (often anonymous) user, and then provide just that user's UID access in the security rules. So it makes me the initial application administrator.

Later you'll then add (or replace) this by a proper ACL system, storing the users who can read a project in the database and then check that from your security rules with something like:

```
".read": "root.child('project_admins').child($UUID).child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank,! So just to make sure: When I go to Firebase > Authentication > and then search for that specific UID, then I don't find any user with this UID. Can I conclude from this that the user for who that line was set up than apparently no longer exists and that line within the Rules no longer effectively does anything? Or am I not looking in the right place to find the user with this UID?

Comment: On the level of the security rules that `AIzaxxx` is nothing more than a string, so there's no enforcement of its existence. It could indeed be that the user has since been deleted from the project, or something like that.